# Post data in Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular

I want to post data in to web api in Angular. I'm using the following code but I'm unable to solve this

```
register() {
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Accept', 'application/json');
    const httpParams = new HttpParams()

        .set('name', this.name.value)
        .set('username', this.username.value)
        .set('email', this.email.value)
        .set('password', this.password.value);


    this.http.post('api', {
        headers: httpHeaders,
        params: httpParams,
        responseType: 'json'
    }).subscribe(data => {

        alert('Register Success!');

      } error =>{


    });
  }
```

Simply this is a registation form, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please look at here, 
there is full explanation given about how to pass data in post request (Angular 2).

[Angular post request demo](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-http-post-example)

```
testRequest() {
  var body = 'username=myusername&password=mypassword';
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  this.http
    .post('/api',
      body, {
        headers: headers
      })
      .subscribe(data => {
            alert('ok');
      }, error => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
      });
```

}

Comment: accoding to my senario how to do that can u update accoding to that